# Updating constraint in UITableViewCell not working properly with UIWebView scrollView when zooming

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiwebview, constraints

I am trying to update the height of a table view cell to match the height of a `UIWebView` scroll view after zooming in. The `UIWebView` is a subview of the table view cell.

on

```
func scrollViewDidEndZooming(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, with view: UIView?, atScale scale: CGFloat) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        print("\nscrollViewDidEndZooming")
        print("webView.scrollView.contentSize.height: \(self.webView.scrollView.contentSize.height)")
        print("webViewHeightConstraint: \(self.webViewHeightConstraint.constant)")

        let height = self.webView.scrollView.contentSize.height
        self.webViewHeightConstraint.constant = height
        myDelegate.reloadTableView()
    }
}
```

In parent controller:

```
func reloadTableView() {
    tableView.beginUpdates()
    tableView.endUpdates() 
}
```

There is html content loaded on the webview. The problem is, after `didEndZooming` is called and the height constraint is updated, it isn't setting properly. The height constraint will grow in size until. It seems to me that setting a height constraint in a tableView cell is somehow creating a feed back loop.

How can I make this work how I expect it to? (it should resize to the zoomed value without having the scrollview grow in size unbounded.)

update:
in

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: WebViewCell.description(), for: indexPath) as! WebViewCell

    //The cell delegate implements the didFinishLoad() function
    cell.delegate = self

    //TODO: I know this is not efficient, will update later.
    if let html = viewModel.emailInfo?.htmlContent {
        cell.loadHTMLString(html)
    }

    return cell
}
```

The cell itself is in a xib file. I put the views inside of a dummy view for now (trying to see if this fixed my issue (it didn't). The web view has constraints on the top, bottom, left, and right edges. The webview also has a height constraint. It is this height constraint, `webViewHeightConstraint`, that I am trying to use to determine the height of the cell.

[image]

This is the log output after a few cycles of zooming in and out. This is printed before the new height constraint is set:

> scrollViewDidEndZooming webView.scrollView.contentSize.height: 962.0
>   webViewHeightConstraint: 509.0
>
> scrollViewDidEndZooming webView.scrollView.contentSize.height: 962.0
>   webViewHeightConstraint: 962.0
>
> scrollViewDidEndZooming webView.scrollView.contentSize.height: 1531.0
>   webViewHeightConstraint: 962.0
>
> scrollViewDidEndZooming webView.scrollView.contentSize.height: 1549.0
>   webViewHeightConstraint: 1531.0
>
> scrollViewDidEndZooming webView.scrollView.contentSize.height: 2566.0
>   webViewHeightConstraint: 1549.0
>
> scrollViewDidEndZooming webView.scrollView.contentSize.height: 2566.0
>   webViewHeightConstraint: 2566.0
>
> scrollViewDidEndZooming webView.scrollView.contentSize.height: 4779.0
>   webViewHeightConstraint: 2566.0
>
> scrollViewDidEndZooming webView.scrollView.contentSize.height: 4779.0
>   webViewHeightConstraint: 4779.0
>
> scrollViewDidEndZooming webView.scrollView.contentSize.height: 10989.0
>   webViewHeightConstraint: 4779.0
>
> scrollViewDidEndZooming webView.scrollView.contentSize.height: 10989.0
>   webViewHeightConstraint: 10989.0
>
> scrollViewDidEndZooming webView.scrollView.contentSize.height: 25110.0
>   webViewHeightConstraint: 10989.0
>
> scrollViewDidEndZooming webView.scrollView.contentSize.height: 25110.0
>   webViewHeightConstraint: 25110.0

Comment: You should provide more code inside `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)` method, how your `tableViewCell` looks like and what is `webViewHeightConstraint`. It's easier and faster to help you if we can have a debug repo.

Comment: You should post some more information to help us e.g. what constraints are setup in the cell, an example of what you are expecting and what you are getting, etc.  If you want to check for a 'feed back loop' then put some logging in the scrollViewDidEndZooming to see if it does indeed execute multiple times.  I would also suggest checking the actual height it's trying to set.  Finally UIWebView is currently deprecated so I would suggest looking into the WKWebView.

Comment: Thanks, I chose UIWebView for several reason. But I will take another look at WKWebView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this instead:

```
func scrollViewDidEndZooming(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, with view: UIView?, atScale scale: CGFloat) {
    self.webHeightConstraint.constant = self.webHeightConstraint.constant * scale

    myDelegate?.reloadTableView()
}
```

This avoids having to reference the contentSize of the webViews scroll view as that doesn't go below the webView size when zooming back out.

Now it doesn't work perfectly because you see the webView zoom into itself and then it snaps to the new size when you finish but it's always going to be like that as nothing is updated until the zooming is finished.

Also don't forget to set the minimumZoom and maximumZoom levels of the scroll view appropriately.

Comment: not referencing the contentSize works. It gets rid of the weird feedback loop that made the scroll view grow in size. I still dont know _why_ this is happening though.

Comment: I think it's because the contentSize never goes below what it is now in that method but the scale does.  So if your cell was 100 points high and you zoom out it might report a scale of 0.5 but it still reports the contentSize as having a height of 100 points.  You can see the effect as when you scroll in but before you stop you can see the content going within the area of the cell/web view.  It's related to how the zooming snaps back if you are not changing the cell size like you are here.

Answer (score 0):

I feel that all what you do is on the fly and it is the problem , you better add a global array of heights initially contains the default height for the table cell , each time a specific webview is zommed in change the corresponding value in the global array with the same index as the that cell and reload the tableview , hook the tableViewCell height as IBOutlet

and do this in cellForRowAt

```
 cell.heightConOfCell.constant = #coressponding value in global array#
```

don't forget to put these to lines before return cell

```
 cell.layoutSubviews()

 cell.layoutIfNeeded()

 return cell
```

I expect from your problem that you are using dynamic tableViewCell height

Comment: What values do you put in this global array? How do you know them in advance?  The original problem is that the UIWebView is zoomed by the user so the final height could be anything really.

Comment: I mean inital height values for every cell , they will be default values if static or if he is using dynamic will be set to current xib height , whenever zoom happens he gets frame and set it to corresponding index

Comment: Everything is happening inside the cell itself.  The UIWebView is a subview of the cell.  When the UIWebView ends zooming then the height of that particular cell should be updated (which is what isn't working).  So for example if the UIWebView is in cell 3 and it is zoomed then cell 3 should resize.  The height required to size to is taken from the UIWebView it doesn't relate in anyway to an array of sizes for the cells.

Comment: new size of cell = old size of cell  + new change of webView frame

Comment: Ahh I see what you are saying now.  That would work but assuming the original requirement is that the cell height is the full height of the contents of the UIWebView it shouldn't be needed as you can just set the height of the cell directly to the height of the UIWebView content height.  In this case it's more likely that the content height is not what it is thought it is.

Comment: it's same to get new size of webview and add it to old view and relayout or set the new height directly to the webview as dynamic height wil work for both cases

Answer (score 0):

i think you are giving a fixed height for tableview cell.

return height as UITableViewAutomaticDimension

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

Comment: Nope it couldn't be that issue because the original question states that the size of the UITableViewCell does change just not how it was hoped it would.  If the height for cells was not set to UITableViewAutomaticDimension then it would not change at all.

Comment: But in the log output the height of webview is updating
if it's not the problem with height he is returning then the problem might be on the constraints